Cannot install postgres on Centos 7 as signature cannot be verified/gpg keys not imported
I am currently trying to access a postgres 12 RDS on a private VPC through an EC2 instance on the same VPC, and in order to do so I am trying to install postgres on this instance (which is a Centos 7 AlmaLinux instance). After the initial attempt, I read that there are EOL and depreciation issues related to postgres 12 on Centos 7, so I followed the guide related to installing older versions of postgres on Centos 7 from here: https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages/#pgredhatoldrepos
However every time I try to yum install
sudo yum install postgresql12-server postgresql12
I get the error:
https://yum-archive.postgresql.org/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
And when I try to access the link manually, it seems there is an error at the site. Is there simply no way to install postgres 12 on Centos 7 now? Or are there alternative ways? Also every time I try to install any single package that isn't even related to postgres, I still get the error above unless I explicitly tell yum to disable the repo like below:
--disablerepo=pgdg12-archive
Is this related? I posted a similar question in stackoverflow before I was redirected here because it would be more appropriate here. Thank you for the help in advanced.

12 will only go out of support in November, so that is not the issue here.

Centos 7 is EOL since 30. June, though ... is there a particular reason to stick with that old release?

It's complicated, but I currently am working on a legacy application that is in production, and I don't have access to the fullstack of the application so I don't know how upgrading it would affect application functionality. Should I press our developers to update? Is it complicated?

I'm not too familiar w/ the RedHat ecosystem, Debian/Ubuntu guy myself. But not getting new patches on a production system in the cloud? Seems like a bad idea.

Where did you get that URL from?  If you go to the postgresql website and select the specs you mention above it tells you to run:
# Install the repository RPM:
sudo yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

# Install PostgreSQL:
sudo yum install -y postgresql12-server


when I do the above, I still get the same error:
https://yum-archive.postgresql.org/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Is there something potentially redirecting it to the wrong link?
After doing the first command, I get:
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-YAAWlo/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-38PGDG.noarch /var/tmp/yum-root-YAAWlo/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package. Error: Nothing to do

You may have to inspect the yum repos you have and get rid of the bung one. @ArthurS

I have removed the only pgdg repo (pgdg-12.repo) in yum.repos and now when I try to sudo yum install the above, it still says nothing to do and no package available when installing postgres. Have I potentially broken something?

I have checked the yum-root-YAWWlo folder and it does have two files: epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm and  pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm. So I imagine that is why the first command does not work, but then why does it say this when I try to install postgresql No package postgresql12-server available. if it is already in the folder? (I only need the client instead of the server, is there an alternative way to do this potentially?)

Hi @ArthurS - when you're futzing w/ yum you should probably read up about it; I just did some research, downloaded the repo rpm and had a look at it (don't ask). I think you will need to edit the file /'etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo, find the lines referencing postrges 12 and set them to enabled.  Change enabled = 0 to enabled = 1, followed by a yum check-update. As I said: DeadRat, errrh, RedHat is not my world.

Just as a quick update, as I ran a bunch of commands prior to it finally working, but I was able to get an antiquated version of postgres (9.2) working with the sudo yum install postgresql command. I am not sure what finally got it to work, but there was some messing around with the enabled repolist and other cached files in the process that might have helped...if I do have a problem with the current version of the postgres client I will follow the above advice, thank you for the help especially with software from an antiquated perspective

Glad you got something working, but 9.2 ... has been out of support for 7 years.

I am mostly using it as a client for what it's worth to connect to a postgres 12 server, before we probably split ways, I guess my last question would be are there any issues I risk running into using an old version of the postgres client?

I'm personally unaware of issues w/ the psql client; there have been CVEs for psqlODBC, possibly for other libraries as well; but given its age no one will have looked for problems in a long time. @ArthurS
